# Some crazy code and crazy data. Insert rows in mysql db (python)

Tags: python, mysql, database, tuples, mysql-python

I'm trying to insert some data (stored in a list of tuples) to my local database. The data is a little inconsistent - some timestamps are `datetime.datetime` while some can be strings. But I don't think that's where my problem is.

First of all, my db schema:

```
+-----------------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field                       | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| store                       | varchar(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| order_no                    | int(11)     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| product_name                | text        | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| product_id                  | int(11)     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| classification              | int(11)     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| order_date                  | datetime    | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| power_complete_time         | datetime    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| stockout_date               | datetime    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| wfi_status                  | tinyint(4)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| qc_status                   | varchar(12) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| scanned_for_shipment_date   | datetime    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| order_delivered_date        | datetime    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| status                      | varchar(50) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| stock_out_status            | varchar(50) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| actual_order_date           | datetime    | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| order_for_today             | tinyint(1)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| dispatched_within_same_day  | tinyint(1)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| stockout_within_same_day    | tinyint(1)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| order_for_yesterday         | tinyint(1)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| dispatched_within_yesterday | tinyint(1)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| stockout_within_yesterday   | tinyint(1)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| eyeframe_less_than_1_pm     | tinyint(1)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |

+-----------------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Next up, my script with the crazy weird data. Again, the data about some dates can be inconsistent that is why I'm testing with a bunch of data rows:

```
import MySQLdb
import datetime

if __name__ == '__main__':

    rows = [
        (u'Lenskart', u'1200667194', u'Prescription Card', u'41420', u'shipping_accessories', datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 27, 4, 12, 56), datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 27, 11, 18, 4), datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 27, 11, 45, 32), u'0', None, datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 28, 3, 24, 17), u'0000-00-00 00:00:00', u'complete', None, datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 27, 9, 42, 56), 0, None, None, 0, None, None, 0),
        (u'Lenskart', u'1200667195', u'Rs.1800 Coupon Booklet ( Rs. 500 Coupons)  - FREE', u'39799', u'shipping_accessories', datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 27, 4, 13, 17), datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 27, 10, 10, 2), datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 27, 10, 53, 32), u'1', None, datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 27, 12, 12, 2), u'0000-00-00 00:00:00', u'complete', u'complete', datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 27, 9, 43, 17), 0, None, None, 0, None, None, 0),
        (u'Lenskart', u'1200667196', u'Vincent Chase RG 172 Gunmetal C3 Eyeglasses', u'58131', u'eyeframe', datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 27, 4, 13, 31), datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 27, 10, 10, 2), datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 27, 12, 54, 34), u'1', None, datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 28, 4, 49, 13), u'0000-00-00 00:00:00', u'complete', None, datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 27, 9, 43, 31), 0, None, None, 0, None, None, 0),
        (u'Lenskart', u'1200667193', u'Prescription Card', u'41420', u'shipping_accessories', datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 27, 4, 11, 10), datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 27, 10, 12, 4), datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 27, 11, 37, 47), u'0', None, datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 27, 19, 51, 13), u'2013-07-29 00:00:00', u'delivered', None, datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 27, 9, 41, 10), 0, None, None, 0, None, None, 0),
        (u'Lenskart', u'1200667193', u'Prescription-Lens PC SV Regular', u'45081', u'prescription_lens', datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 27, 4, 11, 10), datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 27, 10, 12, 4), datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 27, 17, 51, 33), u'0', None, datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 27, 19, 51, 13), u'2013-07-29 00:00:00', u'delivered', None, datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 27, 9, 41, 10), 0, None, None, 0, None, None, 0),
        (u'Lenskart', u'1200667190', u'Rs.1800 Coupon Booklet ( Rs. 500 Coupons)  - FREE', u'39799', u'shipping_accessories', datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 27, 4, 10, 33), datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 27, 10, 7, 4), datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 27, 10, 56, 2), u'1', None, datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 27, 14, 33, 21), u'0000-00-00 00:00:00', u'complete', u'complete', datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 27, 9, 40, 33), 0, None, None, 0, None, None, 0),
        (u'Lenskart', u'1200667187', u'Prescription-Lens CR SV Regular', u'45073', u'prescription_lens', datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 27, 4, 8, 48), datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 27, 9, 58, 2), datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 27, 12, 11, 25), u'0', None, datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 27, 17, 0, 1), u'2013-07-30 00:00:00', u'delivered', None, datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 27, 9, 38, 48), 0, None, None, 0, None, None, 0),
        (u'Lenskart', u'1200667183', u'Rs.1800 Coupon Booklet ( Rs. 500 Coupons)  - FREE', u'39799', u'shipping_accessories', datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 27, 4, 3, 46), datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 27, 11, 44, 3), datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 27, 12, 26, 48), u'1', None, datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 27, 17, 46, 17), u'2013-07-30 00:00:00', u'delivered', None, datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 27, 9, 33, 46), 0, None, None, 0, None, None, 0),
        (u'Lenskart', u'1200667183', u'Prescription-Lens CR SV Regular', u'45073', u'prescription_lens', datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 27, 4, 3, 46), datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 27, 11, 44, 3), datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 27, 13, 50, 35), u'0', None, datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 27, 17, 46, 17), u'2013-07-30 00:00:00', u'delivered', None, datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 27, 9, 33, 46), 0, None, None, 0, None, None, 0),
        (u'Lenskart', u'1200667175', u'Bausch & Lomb Soflens 59 (6 Lenses/box)_S:-4.75 / C:0.00 / A:0 / BC:8.60 / AP:0.00 / CL:', u'90000443', u'contact_lens', datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 27, 3, 58, 6), datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 27, 9, 38, 2), datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 27, 10, 10, 22), u'0', None, datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 27, 12, 32, 17), u'2013-07-29 00:00:00', u'delivered', u'complete', datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 27, 9, 28, 6), 0, None, None, 0, None, None, 0),
        (u'Lenskart', u'1200667171', u'Rs.1800 Coupon Booklet ( Rs. 500 Coupons)  - FREE', u'39799', u'shipping_accessories', datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 27, 3, 55, 56), datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 27, 9, 37, 3), datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 27, 9, 51, 47), u'1', None, datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 27, 12, 59, 50), u'0000-00-00 00:00:00', u'complete', u'complete', datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 27, 9, 25, 56), 0, None, None, 0, None, None, 0),
        (u'Lenskart', u'1200667165', u'Rs.1800 Coupon Booklet ( Rs. 500 Coupons)  - FREE', u'39799', u'shipping_accessories', datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 27, 9, 20), datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 27, 9, 30, 4), datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 27, 10, 24, 35), u'1', None, datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 27, 16, 15, 14), u'2013-07-29 00:00:00', u'delivered', u'complete', datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 27, 14, 50), 0, None, None, 0, None, None, 0),
        (u'Bagskart', u'1200667151', u'Feelgood Backpack FG011-A Navy Blue', u'35607', u'Backpacks', datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 27, 2, 14, 52), u'', datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 27, 12, 50, 15), u'1', None, datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 27, 15, 16, 32), u'2013-07-29 00:00:00', u'delivered', u'complete', datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 27, 7, 44, 52), 0, None, None, 0, None, None, 0),
        (u'Lenskart', u'1200667148', u'Rs.1800 Coupon Booklet ( Rs. 500 Coupons)  - FREE', u'39799', u'shipping_accessories', datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 27, 2, 8, 40), datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 27, 7, 41, 3), datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 27, 7, 50, 37), u'1', None, datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 27, 12, 9, 49), u'2013-07-29 00:00:00', u'complete', u'complete', datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 27, 7, 38, 40), 0, None, None, 0, None, None, 0)
        ]
    db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost",
                         user="root",
                          passwd="",
                          db="inventory")

    cur = db.cursor()

    sql = """INSERT INTO daily_dispatch VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s,
                                                %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s,
                                                %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s,
                                                %s)
                                                """
    row = rows[0]

    cur.execute(sql % (row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4], row[5],
                       row[6], row[7], row[8], row[9], row[10], row[11],
                       row[12], row[13], row[14], row[15], row[16], row[17],
                       row[18], row[19], row[20], row[21]))
    db.commit()

    db.close()
```

The error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Karan\Desktop\Dropbox\Valyoo\Task 3\daily_dispatch phpmyadmin\local\insert.py", line 50, in <module>
    row[18], row[19], row[20], row[21]))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 202, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorclass, errorvalue
ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Card, 41420, shipping_accessories, 2013-07-27 04:12:56, 2013-07-27 11:18:04,\n   ' at line 1")
```

1. I have no clue what's wrong. Anyone help me debug this?
2. Is there a better (visually, and performance-wise) way of inserting the tuple rather than using indexes?

Comment: You need to put quotes around `%s` for all the `varchar` and `text` columns, so that SQL will see them as string values.

Comment: There is problem in SQL syntax, it should be `'%s'` for `text`/`varchar` columns, nothing else as stated by @Barmar.

Comment: @Barmar: Bad idea; use SQL parameters instead. See answers below.

Comment: @vedarthk: The SQL syntax is just fine; but instead of string interpolation, the OP should use SQL parameters, which applies correct escaping based on the value type, prevents SQL injection attacks and lets the database reuse the query plan for subsequent insertions.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I completely agree to your point. I was stating the error in his existing script, right answers are listed below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to properly quote the arguments. However, you don't have to do that manually. Instead, pass the arguments as *the second argument* to `cursor.execute` and MySQLdb will quote them for you:

To insert just the first row:

```
sql = """INSERT INTO daily_dispatch VALUES ({})""".format(
         ', '.join(['%s']*22))
cur.execute(sql, row[0])
```

instead of `cur.execute(sql % row[0])`. It looks like a subtle change, but it makes a world of difference.

To insert all the rows use:

```
cur.executemany(sql, rows)
```

Comment: `cur.executemany(sql, row[0])` gives an error that not enough arguments are passed. `cur.executemany(sql, rows)` work perfectly, though!

Comment: Oops, I wrote `cur.executemany` when I meant `cur.execute`. It's now fixed.

Comment: One question. Why is `executemany` faster than `execute` considerably?

Comment: `executemany` sends one command to the MySQL server with all the values to insert. That's much faster than using a Python loop and many calls to `execute`. The server is written in C and looping over the values in a C-loop is generally faster than doing the equivalent with a Python loop.

Answer (score 2):

You are interpolating your data, leave that to the database adapter, which will handle escaping the various values as appropriate. There is also *no* need to expand the whole list of row values:

```
cur.execute(sql, row)
```

You don't really have to type out all those `%s` placeholders; have Python generate them for you:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO daily_dispatch VALUES ({})".format(', '.join(['%s' for _ in range(len(row[0]))]))
```

Since you have more than one row, have the database loop through them and execute the same query for each row in turn:

```
cur.executemany(sql, rows)
```

No need to loop yourself.

Comment: Just to put emphasis on Martijn's answer, you should always use the DB adapter to properly escape values. If you perform the same query over and over, I would push for a prepared statement. But both are good. OTOH, using bare `%` operator of `string.format()` function is a very bad habit, opening the door to SQL injection.